# Running ssh remote command and grep for a string

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, grep

I want to write script that will remotely run some ssh remote commands. All I need is to grep output of executed command for some special string which will mean that command executed successfully. For example when I run this:

```
ssh user@host "sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop"
```

I get output:

```
Stopping haproxy: [  OK  ]
```

All I need is to find "OK" string to ensure that command executed successfully. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `grep` and check exit status:

```
ssh user@host "sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop | grep -Fq '[  OK  ]'"
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Command ran successfully."
else
    echo "Command failed."
fi
```

You may also place `grep` outside.

```
ssh user@host "sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop" | grep -Fq '[  OK  ]'
```

Other ways to check exit status:

```
command && { echo "Command ran successfully."; }
command || { echo "Command failed."; }
if command; then echo "Command ran successfully."; else echo "Command failed."; fi
```

You can also capture output and compare it with `case` or with `[[ ]]`:

```
OUTPUT=$(exec ssh user@host "sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop")
case "$OUTPUT" in
*'[  OK  ]'*)
    echo "Command ran successfully."
    ;;
*)
    echo "Command failed."
esac

if [[ $OUTPUT == *'[  OK  ]'* ]]; then
    echo "Command ran successfully."
else
    echo "Command failed."
fi
```

And you can embed `$(exec ssh user@host "sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop")` directly as an expression instead of passing output to a variable if wanted.

If `/etc/init.d/haproxy stop` sends messages to stderr instead, just redirect it to stdout so you can capture it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy stop 2>&1
```